# Express - How to dispatch the same path to different router file?

Tags: express

I'm making an app the will let different users see the different root page. Let's say there are two groups: `admin` and `viewer`. What I want to do is like:

```
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
var viewer = require('./routes/viewer');

app.get('/', function(req,res,...) {
    if (req is admin) app.use('/', admin);
    else app.use('/', viewer);
});
```

Is this possible, or I should redirect them to different paths? Thanks!

Comment: Does it give you any errors?

Comment: Well, it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done by redirecting a route to other route according to the requirement.

This can be done using below code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(true) {  //group check
       res.redirect('admin');
    } else {
       res.redirect('viewer')
    }
});

app.use('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('admin')
});

app.use('/viewer', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('viewer')
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I do this but the site responds 404. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh I found I still need to write `router.get('/',...)` in admin.js, rather than `router.get('/admin',...)`. Why? BTW this will crash all others routing.

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai Edited dummy working code. Please check if this works for you.